# Ports open, but no one can connect

Tags: c++, networking, sfml, portforwarding

I am programming a server system for a small RPG game made with SFML. This is my first project since we switched our ISP to Comcast and I am having trouble with people connecting to the server. I can connect locally fine and all of the port checking tools say that the port is open, but my friends cannot connect using my external IP. I turned my firewall off on my router and on my computer to see if it'd help the situation at all, but the same thing is occurring.

Comcast gave me an Arris TG862G-CT router.

Here's an image of the port forwarding page:

[image]

The port is shown as open, but my client cannot connect:

[image]

Comment: Not easy to diagnose network trouble in this kind of forum but, off the top of my head, are you sure you are using the correct external IP (type IP into google)? Is the PC running the software really IP 10.0.0.12? Also if you kill a program sometimes the port it was using remains blocked for a few minutes before clearing. Try to close your program nicely each time.

Comment: Yes, the IP assigned to my computer is 10.0.0.12. That is not my external IP, which should be used by other people to connect to my server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which language you are using, but many make a distinction between opening a port with the host address 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, and localhost. Many times you will need to use 0.0.0.0 to connect from an external pc where as 127.0.0.1 and localhost are used as a loopback and only accessible by you.

Comment: C++ - I understand that 127.0.0.1 is a loopback. My internal ip, the ip assigned to my computer, is 10.0.0.12.

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps you are connected locally while your friend is trying to connect externally therefore blocking him from connecting?

Comment: No, the server is set up to handle multiple connections.